# How to get the url of your backend api to use it in jquery in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-core, swagger

I am writing a login form and I need to make an authentication for the username and password.
The form is written in dreamweaver html code. And the database is local in visual studio .net core code. I am still trying to figure out a way to use $post and $get methods, but I even can't write the url correctly. I am using swagger to host my api.

Here is my visual studio controller code :

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using authentication.Models;
using authentication.Repository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Taskb.Controllers
{

    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        private UsersRepository users = new UsersRepository();
        private int count = 0;

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<user>> GetAllUser()
        {
            return users.GetAllUsers();

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<user> CreateUser( user newUser)
        {
            foreach (user item in users.GetAllUsers())
            {

                if (newUser.username == item.username && newUser.password == item.password)
                {
                    count++;
                }

            }

            if (count == 0)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Username or password incorrect");
            }

            return Ok("Authentication Successfull");
        }

    }
 }
```

And here is my html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Roy Daher</title>
    <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale 1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"  
type="text/javascript"></script>   
<!--include jQuery Validation Plugin-->  
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js"  
type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>

<body bgcolor="#F1F1F1" class="body">
    
    <div class="cont" >
        <div class="top"></div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
        <div class="center">
        
    
    <form id="form" method="post">
        <!--<div class="image">
            <img src="images/28-287073_elonlol-discord-emoji-elon-musk-laughing-deer-hd.png" width="282" height="290" alt="Picture" class="elon">
        </div>-->
        
        <div class="container">
            <label for="user"><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="user" required id="userinput">
            
            <label for="pass"><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pass" required id="passinput">
            
            <button id="loginButton" type="button">Login</button>
            <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember">
        </div>
        
         <div class="container" style="background-color:#F1F1F1">

    <span class="forgot">Forgot <a href="pages/PassRecovery.html" target="_blank" >password?</a></span>
  </div>
        
        
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    
    
</body>
    
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
      
      var inputVal = document.getElementById("userinput").value;
      var passVal = document.getElementById("passinput").value;
      
      var obj ={    
                    username:inputVal,
                    password:passVal
                };
      console.log(obj);
     
    $.post("https://44332/api/User",
    {
        
    },
    
    });
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: It's true that the post method `CreateUser` in your controller can be called via post request with url `https://localhost:44332/api/User` , but you should make sure the input parameter type are consistent or you'll get 415 error. You may refer to my code snippet below.

Comment: How is it going on sir? Pls feel free to share your further issue, and if you feel my post is helpful to you, could you pls accept it as the answer? Many thanks for your reply in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your post method should use `[FromBody] user newUser` as the input parameter like below:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<user> CreateUser([FromBody] user newUser)
        {
            List<user> users = new List<user> {
                new user{ username="a",password="a"},
                new user{ username="b",password="b"},
                new user{ username="c",password="c"}
            };
            foreach (user item in users)
            {

                if (newUser.username == item.username && newUser.password == item.password)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count == 0)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, "Username or password incorrect");
            }

            return Ok("Authentication Successfull");
        }
```

And your ajax request should send like this:

```
<button  id="loginButton">login</button>
    <script>
        $("#loginButton").click(function(){
            var obj ={
                        username:"a",
                        password:"a"
                    };
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://localhost:44317/api/user",
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(obj),
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            })
        });
    </script>
```